# Spring Roo model populated from REST service (no persistence)

Tags: spring-roo

I'm building a small web-application, that has no local persistence. It loads data from a remote RESTful end point.

It has one Model object, called Order. When the webapp receives a request such as example.com/order/1234 I want the web app to make a GET request (From a Service layer?) to the remote REST end point and then populate my Domain Model.

What is the best way to go about this? 
Is it possible & worthwhile to use roo in any useful way without having a persistence layer set up?

Answer (score -1):

2 options:

- use the H2 persistence provider as its in memory only
- create roo entity as normal, then push in all the methods and override to use a local HashMap.  I have done this before as follows:

  ```
  @RooJavaBean
  @RooToString
  @RooJpaActiveRecord(versionField="", identifierField="name", identifierType=String.class, versionType=Byte.class)
  @RooJson
  public class MonitorMetric {
  static Map<String, MonitorMetric> data=new HashMap<String, MonitorMetric>();

  @Id
  private String name;

  long totTime;
  long minTime=Long.MAX_VALUE;
  long maxTime=Long.MIN_VALUE;
  int countStarted;
  int countFinished;

  @DateTimeFormat(style = "SS")
  private Date lastAttempt;
  @DateTimeFormat(style = "SS")
  private Date lastSuccess;
  @DateTimeFormat(style = "SS")
  private Date lastFailure;

  public double getAvgTime() {
      return (countFinished>0 ? totTime/countFinished : 0);
  }

  public String getName() {
      return this.name;
  }

  public void setName(String id) {
      this.name = id;
  }

  public static long countMonitorMetrics() {
      return data.size();
  }

  public static List<MonitorMetric> findAllMonitorMetrics() {
      return new ArrayList<MonitorMetric>(data.values());
  }

  public static List<MonitorMetric> findMonitorMetricEntries(int firstResult, int maxResults) {
      int lastResult = (firstResult+maxResults > data.size() ? data.size() : firstResult+maxResults);
      return new ArrayList<MonitorMetric>(data.values()).subList(firstResult, lastResult);
  }

  public static MonitorMetric findMonitorMetric(String name) {
      if (name == null || name.length() == 0) return null;
      return data.get(name);
  }

  public void persist() {
      data.put(getName(), this);
  }

  public MonitorMetric merge() {
      data.put(getName(), this);
      return this;
  }

  public void remove() {
      data.remove(getName());
  }

  public void flush() {
  }

  public void clear() {
      data.clear();
  }
  }
  ```